# Time Zone issue in R

Tags: r, timezone, time-series

I have a time-series object `dat` as

```
dat <- structure(list(timestamp = c("2015-07-01T00:00:06+05:30", "2015-07-01T00:00:36+05:30", 
"2015-07-01T00:01:06+05:30", "2015-07-01T00:01:36+05:30", "2015-07-01T00:02:06+05:30", 
"2015-07-01T00:02:37+05:30"), value = c(110535.421875, 110516.6484375, 
110398.25, 110381.5703125, 110392.15625, 110471.609375)), .Names = c("timestamp", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This object is associated with a timezone offset of 05:30, which is of "Asia/Kolkata". Whenever I try to convert the timestamp, I face following issues:

1. with `as.POSIXct(strptime(dat$timestamp,format ="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"))`, it outputs empty strings
2. If I remove timezone information in `strptime()`, it gets automatically converted to the timezone of system, i.e., `as.POSIXct(strptime(dat$timestamp,format ="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))` . In other words, it takes timezone of the system.

How should I always force the timezone to be the same as associated with the original data object?

Comment: What is the source of these timestamps?

Comment: India, +5:30 offset. I can work with the second option. But I have some other readings which are in US timezone.

Comment: I think you are going to need to convert `05:30` into a timezone string which `strptime()` can handle.

Comment: `strptime` is the POSIXlt version of `as.POSIXct`, so you don't need both.

Comment: `%z` doesn't take a colon in it, so take it out: `as.POSIXct(sub('\\+05:', ' +05', dat$timestamp), format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')`

Comment: still not using `z` for conversions. My concern is how can we convert the input time to the time zone specified by `z`

Comment: It converts for me. If you're going to wrap `strptime` in `as.POSIXct`, you'll need to re-specify the timezone, but there's no need to use both anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Format %z can be used for input or output: it is a character string, conventionally plus or minus followed by two digits for hours and two for minutes. So you need to clean up the data first to change +05:30 into +0530.

```
strptime(gsub("05:30", "0530",dat$timestamp), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

If it can contain a range of time zones in the data, assuming the data is in a standard format all the time, you can do this to remove the last semicolon from `dat$timestamp`:

```
strptime(gsub("(.*)\\:(.*)", "\\1\\2", dat$timestamp), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Answer (score 0):

`lubridate` is your friend. It was written because the basic R functionality for handling dates and times is complete, but tiresome and unforgiving. `lubridate` is (comparatively) easy, flexible, and very forgiving of minor differences in format, tokens, etc.

```
install.packages("lubridate")
require(lubridate)
# the "z!*" will correctly parse any of these:
# "+0530", "+5:30", "+05:30"
dat$parsedTime <- parse_date_time(dat$timestamp, orders="ymd hms z!*")
#
# now print that
#
dat

format(dat$parsedTime, tz="Asia/Kolkata")
```

Internally, POSIXct objects are represented numerically in Unix time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time ) which has no time zone of its own, so you specify the time zone you want when you print. By default, it's usually displayed in the time zone of the R machine, but the default displayed time zone can be changed by setting the `tzone` attribute, like so:

```
 attr(dat$parsedTime, "tzone") <- "Asia/Kolkata"
```

Cheers

Jason